# If a programmer designs a class, (for example class Bitter), are objects created from that class known as type Bitter?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

Trying to understand what is considered a type. Like in the title, when you create two objects from one class, are they considered to be the same type? Bitter type? Since Classes create objects with a unique ID, data field(instance variables), and behaviour(instance methods). Despite this, any instance that is instantiated in the class has similar traits regarding the data fields and behaviour so would it be safe to say that any object created with one particular class is a type of that class?

If this question still does not make sense, I am trying to understand what an exercise in an introduction to python is asking of me. So here is the question:
Design a class named Point to represent a point with x- and y-coordinates. The class contains:
....
....
.a method named distance that returns the distance from this point to another point of the Point type.

Problem is, this class only takes one instance at a time but the instructions are asking for two points(x1,y1, x2, y2). So would two types considered Point type if outside of the class I had stored what the class returned?
For example:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y

    def distance(thisPoint):
        #additional code that does what the instructions specify
        return distanceFromThisPointToAnother
def main():
    x1,y1,x2,y2 = eval(input("Enter two points: "))
    p1 = point(x1,y1) #Would this variable be considered point type
    p2 = point(x2,y2) #Would this variable be considered "another point of Point type"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the terminology is that they are both "Point objects" or "Point **instances**".

Your `Point` class is a `type`, meaning it is an instance of the `type` object in python:

```
>>> isinstance(Point, type)
True
```

Your actual points are not `type` objects:

```
>>> isinstance(p1, type)
False
```

But it is an instance of `Point`:

```
>>> isinstance(p1, Point)
True
```

With regards to your exercise question, one thing you may not have considered / tried is that the method can take the other point **as an argument**:

```
    def distance(thisPoint,otherPoint):
        if not isinstance(otherPoint, Point):
            raise TypeError("argument must be a Point")
        # do calculation here!
        NotImplemented #for this demo
```

Then you can use the method using **both points** by using the method on one and the other as an argument:

```
distance = p1.distance(p2)
```

Assuming the order of the points doesn't matter you could use the method on `p2` instead and get the same result:

```
distance = p2.distance(p1)
```

You could also use the method directly from the class and specify both points as arguments if that seems cleaner code to you:

```
distance = Point.distance(p1, p2)
```

All three of these would give you the same result

Comment: The problem with this is that they specified the class to have two private data fields x and y, which represent get methods. I've written it like so in the code in my question

Comment: So?   `otherPoint.__x` will work fine if it is written in a method in the `Point` class...

Answer (score 0):

In a word: yes.

There are rigorous definitions of words like "type" and "kind" and "instance" and "class" that can apply in academic cases, particularly for languages that have very expressive types. There may therefore be academic cases where the type system breaks down. (For example, a subclass of Point that breaks [Liskov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) may not be considered to be a "type" of Point.) In practice in Python for this kind (hah) of case, it's reasonable to call it a "type".

I think what the assignment is saying is that you don't have to support other constructs that can express the same *data* as an instance of Point does. For example, you could write code that allows you to describe the distance between a Point and a tuple. Allowing operations that support types that you can *treat* as the type you need is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and it's a pretty idiomatic part of Python. I think your assignment is explicitly saying you don't have to do that for this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
class Bitter(object):
    pass

print(Bitter().__class__)  # <class '__main__.Bitter'>
print(type(Bitter()))      # <class '__main__.Bitter'>
print(type(Bitter()) == Bitter)      # True
print(isinstance(Bitter(), Bitter))  # True
```

But if subclasses are involved things change slightly:

```
class ReallyBitter(Bitter):
    pass

print(type(Bitter()))  # <class '__main__.ReallyBitter'>
print(isinstance(ReallyBitter(), Bitter))  # True
```

In your case the method needs to be defined like so:

```
def distance(self, other_point):
```

and then called like:

```
p1.distance(p2)
```

So perhaps your confusion arises from the fact that when you call a method on an object, the `self` argument is implicitly passed. Note that `self` is not a special keyword or anything, I just mean the first argument of an ordinary method in a class which refers to the instance of the class that the method is being called on.

Comment: Note that python's pep8 document prefers isinstance() over type() for explicitly checking the type of an object

Comment: @TomBarron well no... to "explicitly check the type of an object" you must use `type`, to explicitly check if something **is** an **instance** of a type then obviously you would use `isinstance`.

Comment: @Tadhg You got me. :) I was trying to point out that pep8 says, "Object type comparisons should always use isinstance() instead of comparing types directly." Maybe I should've just quoted it the first time.

Comment: @TomBarron quote and [Link! (since section is so big it is easier to _search_ page for `isinstance` then to scroll)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)